# tmux copy line across line break

Tags: tmux

I started using tmux to have many panes open at once, but whenever I have a vertical split I find it hard to copy and select lines. How do I make my mouse selection follow line breaks like how my normal bash does?

Also, is there a way to select part of a line and continue selecting the rest of it after I take my finger off the Shift key?

Answer (score 23):

You can use the "zoom pane" feature by pressing `prefix + z`.
The currently active pane will become full screen (press `prefix + z` to toggle) and now you can do mouse selection as if there are no splits.

Comment: Wow!  Lotta comments here.... Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot......For people that are new to TMux and not that experienced with the tmux configs.... this is BY FAR THE BEST ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 2):

there are configurations to enable mouse actions:

```
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on                 #resize panel with mouse
set -g mouse-select-window on               #select window with mouse
setw -g mode-mouse on                       #Make mouse useful in copy mode
```

try adding them in your tmux.conf

Comment: I already have those in my tmux.conf, but they dont allow you to use the mouse to copy a line following a line break. Using the mouse will allow me to select a rectangular block, which don't encompass the text that's outside the rectangle, but part of the same line.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an unresolved (yet closed) issue, see [Don't yank newlines in line-wrapped commands #530](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/530).

To move this forward, I would suggest:

- Opening a new issue on GitHub
- Ask for the ungarbled patch proposed [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/530#issuecomment-247430269)
- Report back to the maintainers if that solves the problem.